# The whole page gets refresh while using Captcha refresh

Tags: html, asp.net, captcha

I have used the captcha refresh button to refresh the captcha code, but the scenario is that when I click on the refresh image, the whole form gets refreshed. Please help. Also see the code below:-

```
<table style="width: 583px;">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" class="txtfld-popup"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter your Full Name" ControlToValidate="Fullname" Display="Dynamic" Style="font-size: 13px;"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender4" runat="server" TargetControlID="FullName" WatermarkText="Enter Your Full Name"></cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Contact No.</td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" class="txtfld-popup" runat="server" MaxLength="10" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode<48 || event.keyCode>57)event.returnValue=false;"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter Contact No." Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="ContactNo" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" Style="font-size: 13px;"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please enter valid Contact No." Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="ContactNo" ValidationExpression="^\d{10}$" Style="font-size: 13px;"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                <cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender5" runat="server" TargetControlID="ContactNo" WatermarkText="Enter Your Contact No."></cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Purpose </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" class="txtfld-popup" ValidationGroup="VG"></asp:TextBox>
                <cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TextBoxWatermarkExtender6" runat="server" TargetControlID="Purpose" WatermarkText="Enter Your Purpose"></cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>

                <div>
                    <cc1:CaptchaControl ID="CaptchaControl1" runat="server" CaptchaBackgroundNoise="Low" CaptchaLength="5"
                        CaptchaHeight="60" CaptchaWidth="200" CaptchaMinTimeout="5" CaptchaMaxTimeout="240"
                        FontColor="#D20B0C" NoiseColor="#B1B1B1" Width="150" />
                </div>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                               <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" ImageUrl="~/images/refresh.png" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" />
                <br />

                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" MaxLength="5"></asp:TextBox>

                <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator2" ErrorMessage="Invalid. Please try again." OnServerValidate="ValidateCaptcha"
                    runat="server" />
                <p style="margin-top: 3px; margin-bottom: 3px;">
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSend_Click" class="button-form" Width="100" />
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Reset" OnClick="btnReset_Click" class="button-form" Width="100" CausesValidation="false" /></td>
        </tr>
```

Also see the code behind for your reference:-

```
protected void ValidateCaptcha(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    Captcha1.ValidateCaptcha(txtCaptcha.Text.Trim());
    e.IsValid = Captcha1.UserValidated;
    if (e.IsValid)
    {
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "ResponseDialog", "$(document).ready(function(){ResponseDialog();});", true);
        SendMail();
    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: You are using runat = "server" attribute that makes the page to refresh. You need to use ajax if you don't want your page to refresh.

Comment: I just want to refresh the captcha code part. Can you help me in using ajax ? Please

Comment: Please post your code so that we may help.

Comment: i suggest to use update panel

Comment: @Manu: Please see the code, :-  protected void ValidateCaptcha(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
    {
        Captcha1.ValidateCaptcha(txtCaptcha.Text.Trim());
        e.IsValid = Captcha1.UserValidated;
        if (e.IsValid)
        {
          //  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Valid Captcha!');", true);
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "ResponseDialog", "$(document).ready(function(){ResponseDialog();});", true);
            SendMail();
        } and the HTML are given above in the question
    }

Comment: You could have edited this in your question itself. Its really hard to understand. I would suggest, edit your question and show this code in your question itself so that everybody could see it. :)

Comment: @dazzlingkumar: can u suggest how ?

Comment: Instead of onservervalidate and calling validateCaptcha function server side, You can use onclientvalidate and call the same function but this time you have to call function using ajax.
Go through the link below just to know how ajax actually works.
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx
You can even go through http://jquery.com/ to learn everything about ajax

Comment: @Manu: I want to validate using server-side.

Comment: In your UI page put the custom validator inside update panel and content template thats all see this link http://www.asp.net/Ajax/documentation/live/overview/UpdatePanelOverview.aspx

Comment: @dazzlingkumar: Please help dude, i am not getting the exact result, I tried with update panel also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally added a update panel for the solution:-

```
  <tr>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                        <table>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <cc1:CaptchaControl ID="Captcha1" runat="server" CaptchaBackgroundNoise="Low" CaptchaLength="5"
                                                        CaptchaHeight="60" CaptchaWidth="200" CaptchaMinTimeout="5" CaptchaMaxTimeout="240"
                                                        FontColor="#D20B0C" NoiseColor="#B1B1B1" />
                                                </td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgRefreshButton" ImageUrl="~/images/refresh.png" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>

                                        </table>
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                    <Triggers>
                                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ImgRefreshButton" EventName="Click" />
                                    </Triggers>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCaptcha" runat="server" MaxLength="5"></asp:TextBox>

                                <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" ErrorMessage="Invalid. Please try again." OnServerValidate="ValidateCaptcha"
                                    runat="server" />


                                <p style="margin-top: 3px; margin-bottom: 3px;">
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblLeaveNo2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                </p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
```

And it is working for me. :)